# How to hardcode array of strings inside lightning expression?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am not sure if this post is duplicate of this [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158108/use-custom-label-in-lightning-component-array-of-string-attribute) but I was intrigued by it and kept trying several methods and stumbled on this and could not get it work even the basic scenario:

**Snippet 1:**

*HelloWorld.app:*

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:iteration items="Mon,Tue" var="item">
        {!item}<br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

*Output:*

[image]

**Snippet 2:**(Does not work)

*HelloWorld.app*

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:iteration items="{! 'Mon,Tue' }" var="item">
        {!item}<br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

*Output:*

[image]

What is wrong with the code in snippet 2? Any clues?

**NOTE:** I am trying this on Winter'17 Org.

Comment: Just to let you know, one of the answer from my original question is to set the value of the child component attribute from the parent JS controller: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158108/use-custom-label-in-lightning-component-array-of-string-attribute

Comment: @FabienTaillon Thanks for that. Actually I am following RSS  feed for your question and reading every answer when it is posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the error you got, it looks like `aura:iteration` does not like *items* being pointed to `{!v.something}` expression which evaluates to a String.

For`items="Mon,Tue"` it seems `aura:iteration` automagically wraps in a array when the body is generated.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <!-- {! 'Mon,Tue' } => evaluates to a String -->
    <aura:iteration items="{! 'Mon,Tue' }" var="item">
        {!item}<br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

Even this won't work too:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="days" type="String" default="Mon,Tue"/>
    <!-- {!v.days} => again evaluates to a String -->
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.days}" var="item">
        {!item}<br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```